# Can't find .net provider SimpleMembership MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I'm trying the simplemembership in ASP.NET MVC4 but have encountered some problems. I have been googleing around and found recommendations to put the following code in a file called _AppStart.cshtml in the root directory.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("marabr", "Users", "id", "name", "password", true);
```

But when I do so I get the following error message.

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

My connectionstring is like this

```
<add name="marabr" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=marabr;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=marabr;Password=marabr;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and my provider

```
<add name="SimpleMembership" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working. If I put this code in let say some controller code it work perfectly but then I get in trouble with several calls to it. It is just in _AppStart and if I put it in Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs I have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out you web config file and add entity framework connection

```
<add name="marabr" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.****.csdl|res://*/Models.****.ssdl|res://*/Models.****.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=****;persist security info=True;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I use any framework in particular. I go with stored procedure.